# Which items to buy if the best one will always be stolen?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization, combinatorial-game-theory, discrete-optimization

**The Problem:**

A store sells $N$ items. Each item $i$ is priced at $p_i \ge 0$ and you value the $i$th item at $x_i \ge p_i$. You can carry at most two items.

To complicate matters, when you leave the store you will be attacked by a bully who will steal the item you value most among the items you have bought.
(If you buy no items the bully leaves you alone; if you buy one item he steals it and if you buy items $i$ and $j$, say, with $x_i \ge x_j$ he steals item $i$).

*Which items do you buy?*

I am wondering whether this problem has an explicit, "simple" solution. If not, is it possible to prove that there is no simple solution?

The only way of solving it I can come up with is brute force:

**Example with $N=3$:**

$$x_1 = 10, x_2 = 5, x_3 = 4$$
$$p_1 = 3, p_2 = 2, p_3 = 1.$$

- If you buy two items you can keep either item 2 or item 3 since item 1 would always be stolen.

1. If you want to keep item 2 you must also buy item 1 and so you get $5-(3+2)=0$
2. If you want to keep item 3 you must also buy either item 1 or item 2. In the first case you get $4-3-1=0$; in the second case you get $4-1-2=1.$

- If you buy only one item it will be stolen but you will have paid a positive price for it, so you get less than zero.
- If you buy no item you get zero.

So in this example the optimal thing to do is to buy items 2 and 3.

Comment: So I want to maximize $x_j-p_i-p_j$?

Comment: Can we assume that the items you value more highly cost more?  That is, if $x_i\geq x_j$ is it always true that $p_i\geq p_j$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You want to choose $i$ and $j$ to maximize $\min\{x_i, x_j}-p_i -p_j$

Comment: @saulspatz No, the prices can be any nonnegative numbers. We only assume that no item's price is higher than it's value to you.

Comment: So the optimal solution is to get the most value while spending the least amount of money. When you say "simple" solution, do you mean a mathematical function of some sort, or do you mean a quick algorithm that can compute it? I do not think there is a way to solve the problem without examining both all of the $x_i$ values, and all of the $p_i$ values, which means that there isn't a good reason to exclude using a computer program to "brute force" this problem.

Comment: For each $i$ let $q_i=\min\{p_j|x_j>x_i\}$  Then the problem is to maximize $x_i-p_i-q_i$.

Comment: @saulspatz I would accept this as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $i$ let $q_i=\min\{p_j|x_j>x_i\}.$ Then the problem is to maximize $x_i-p_i-q_i$.